# How to get city name from latitude and longitude coordinates in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

How might I obtain the city name in Google Maps if I have latitude and longitude coordinates of a town or area?

I tried using the latitude, longitude and I got country but I don't know how to get city name.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

From a [`Geocoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) object, you can call the [`getFromLocation(double, double, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) method. It will return a list of [`Address`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) objects that have a method [`getLocality()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getLocality()).

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
}
else {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I am getting error which says "Timed out waiting for response from server". I have added Internet permission. Do it need something else?

Comment: I dont remember I needed anything else. Try with other lat and long.

Comment: sometimes getLocality() returns null and city name stays at mAdminArea

Comment: For addresses in the USA (and some other countries) use getAdminArea() to return the state

Comment: Please do not use the Geocoder. It throws exception on many devices and requires restart to work again properly.

Comment: I tested your code on multiple devices but it returns glpc error. what should I do to fix it?

Comment: `getLocality()` sometimes return **null**. `getAdminArea()` gives the province or state in Canada while `getSubAdminAread()` gives the city but it's weird e.g. "Toronto division"

Comment: Always returns null to me .=

Answer (score 28):

I am using this code. You can also your this for getting city and other details about a Latitude and longitude :

```
public class getReverseGeoCoding {
    private String Address1 = "", Address2 = "", City = "", State = "", Country = "", County = "", PIN = "";
    
    public void getAddress() {
        Address1 = "";
        Address2 = "";
        City = "";
        State = "";
        Country = "";
        County = "";
        PIN = "";
        
        try {
            
            JSONObject jsonObj = parser_Json.getJSONfromURL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + Global.curLatitude + ","
                    + Global.curLongitude + "&sensor=true&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
            String Status = jsonObj.getString("status");
            if (Status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                JSONArray Results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
                JSONObject zero = Results.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray address_components = zero.getJSONArray("address_components");
                
                for (int i = 0; i < address_components.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject zero2 = address_components.getJSONObject(i);
                    String long_name = zero2.getString("long_name");
                    JSONArray mtypes = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
                    String Type = mtypes.getString(0);
                    
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(long_name) == false || !long_name.equals(null) || long_name.length() > 0 || long_name != "") {
                        if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("street_number")) {
                            Address1 = long_name + " ";
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("route")) {
                            Address1 = Address1 + long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("sublocality")) {
                            Address2 = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("locality")) {
                            // Address2 = Address2 + long_name + ", ";
                            City = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_2")) {
                            County = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                            State = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("country")) {
                            Country = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("postal_code")) {
                            PIN = long_name;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // JSONArray mtypes = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
                    // String Type = mtypes.getString(0);
                    // Log.e(Type,long_name);
                }
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public String getAddress1() {
        return Address1;
        
    }
    
    public String getAddress2() {
        return Address2;
        
    }
    
    public String getCity() {
        return City;
        
    }
    
    public String getState() {
        return State;
        
    }
    
    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
        
    }
    
    public String getCounty() {
        return County;
        
    }
    
    public String getPIN() {
        return PIN;
        
    }
    
}
```

[For more detail on how to get Google Map Api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key)

**JSON PARSER CLASS**

```
public class parser_Json {
    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {

        // initialize
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jObject = null;

        // http post
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jObject;
    }

}
```

You can get more info from this question : [Get the particular address using latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515682/get-the-particular-address-using-latitude-and-longitude/16515848#16515711)

Comment: @ErumHannan You can do like this in your service ** new getReverseGeoCoding().getCity(); ** this will return you the current City or lat, long which is from a Global class.

Comment: I used you code but it returns an error which says 
{"error_message":"You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http:\/\/g.co\/dev\/maps-no-account","results":[],"status":"REQUEST_DENIED"}
How should I fix it?

Answer (score 12):

**Try this**

```
  List<Address> list = geoCoder.getFromLocation(location
            .getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
    if (list != null & list.size() > 0) {
        Address address = list.get(0);
        result = address.getLocality();
        return result;
```

Answer (score 9):

Just Use this method and pass your lat, long.

```
public static void getAddress(Context context, double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {

//Set Address
try {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {



        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL

        Log.d(TAG, "getAddress:  address" + address);
        Log.d(TAG, "getAddress:  city" + city);
        Log.d(TAG, "getAddress:  state" + state);
        Log.d(TAG, "getAddress:  postalCode" + postalCode);
        Log.d(TAG, "getAddress:  knownName" + knownName);

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return;
}
```

Comment: What does this add that isn't already in the existing answers?

Comment: @OrangeDog a simplified method with Try Catch exceptions. So others can understand it easily.

Answer (score 8):

try below code hope use full for you:-

```
CityAsyncTask cst = new CityAsyncTask(HomeScreenUserLocation.this,
                latitude, longitude);
        cst.execute();

        String lo = null;
        try {
            lo = cst.get().toString();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and **AsyncTask**

```
public class CityAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    Activity act;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    public CityAsyncTask(Activity act, double latitude, double longitude) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.act = act;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(act, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
                    longitude, 1);
            Log.e("Addresses", "-->" + addresses);
            result = addresses.get(0).toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 private class MatchingNearByLocationTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
 {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        jsonStr = getLocationInfo(Latitude, Longitude).toString();
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            Log.i("location--??", jsonStr);

            JSONObject jsonObj;
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                String Status = jsonObj.getString("status");
                if (Status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                    JSONArray Results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
                    JSONObject zero = Results.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONArray address_components = zero
                            .getJSONArray("address_components");

                    for (int i = 0; i < address_components.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject zero2 = address_components
                                .getJSONObject(i);
                        String long_name = zero2.getString("long_name");
                        JSONArray mtypes = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
                        String Type = mtypes.getString(0);
                        if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_2")) {
                            // Address2 = Address2 + long_name + ", ";
                            String City = long_name;
                            Log.d(" CityName --->", City + "");
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {

        super.onCancelled();
        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }

}




private JSONObject getLocationInfo(double lat, double lng) {

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
            "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
                    + lat + "," + lng + "&sensor=false");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var geocoder;
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

geocoder.geocode(
{'latLng': latlng}, 
function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var add= results[0].formatted_address ;
                var  value=add.split(",");

                count=value.length;
                country=value[count-1];
                state=value[count-2];
                city=value[count-3];
                alert("city name is: " + city);
            }
            else  {
                alert("address not found");
            }
    }
     else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
    }
}
```

);

Answer (score 2):

try using this api :

URL ": http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=23.042615,72.547805@key=put your map api key

Press enter and get the results

Answer (score 1):

I got new way to resolve this issue. Here  I have used google http service to get total information of location based on longitude and latitude. You just need to pass latitude and longitude in url and your api key (ex : latlng=21.1497409, 79.08747970000002 & key=YOUR API KEY). Here is my get service in `ExampleService`Class

```
 getService(url) {

    return this.http.get(url).map((data: any) => data.json())

}
```

this you can put anywhere you want and just call below service from component where you need location data

```
this._exampleService.getService("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=21.1497409, 79.08747970000002&key=YOUR API KEY").subscribe(getplaceData => {
            var placeDataDest: any;
            placeDataDest = getplaceData;
            console.log("i got place id yeee " + placeDataDest['results'][0]['place_id']);
            console.log("i got place details yeee " + placeDataDest['results']);
        });
```

similarly find city name....hope you will find this useful

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below code

```
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
     List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
     String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
     String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
     String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you have a list:

```
Address address = list.get(0);
String cityname = address.getLocality();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject jsonObject = com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject.parseObject(data);
        if("OK".equals(jsonObject.getString("status"))){
            String formatted_address;
            JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            if(results != null && results.size() > 0){
                com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject object = results.getJSONObject(0);
                String addressComponents = object.getString("address_components");
                formatted_address = object.getString("formatted_address");
                Log.e("amaya","formatted_address="+formatted_address+"--url="+url);
                if(findCity){
                    boolean finded = false;
                    JSONArray ac = JSONArray.parseArray(addressComponents);
                    if(ac != null && ac.size() > 0){
                        for(int i=0;i<ac.size();i++){
                            com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject jo = ac.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONArray types = jo.getJSONArray("types");
                            if(types != null && types.size() > 0){
                                for(int j=0;j<ac.size();j++){
                                    String string = types.getString(i);
                                    if("administrative_area_level_1".equals(string)){
                                        finded = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(finded) break;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("amaya","city="+formatted_address);
                }else{
                    Log.e("amaya","poiName="+hotspotPoi.getPoi_name()+"--"+hotspotPoi);
                }
                if(hotspotPoi != null) hotspotPoi.setPoi_name(formatted_address);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new AmayaEvent.GeoEvent(hotspotPoi));
            }
        }
```

this is a method to parse google feedback data.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude, mMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

                String locality = addresses.get(0).getLocality(); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                String subLocality = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality(); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                //String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                String address1 = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                String address2 = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
               // String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.JSONObject

fun parseLocation(response: String): GeoLocation? {

val geoCodes by lazy { doubleArrayOf(0.0, 0.0) }

val jObj = JSONObject(response)
if (jObj.has(KEY_RESULTS)) {

    val jArrResults = jObj.getJSONArray(KEY_RESULTS)
    for (i in 0 until jArrResults.length()) {
        val jObjResult = jArrResults.getJSONObject(i)
        //getting latitude and longitude
        if (jObjResult.has(KEY_GEOMETRY)) {
            val jObjGeometry = jObjResult.getJSONObject(KEY_GEOMETRY)

            if (jObjGeometry.has(KEY_LOCATION)) {
                val jObjLocation = jObjGeometry.getJSONObject(KEY_LOCATION)
                if (jObjLocation.has(KEY_LAT)) {
                    geoCodes[0] = jObjLocation.getDouble(KEY_LAT)
                }

                if (jObjLocation.has(KEY_LNG)) {
                    geoCodes[1] = jObjLocation.getDouble(KEY_LNG)
                }
            }
        }

        var administrativeAreaLevel1: String? = null

        //getting city
        if (jObjResult.has(KEY_ADDRESS_COMPONENTS)) {

            val jArrAddressComponents = jObjResult.getJSONArray(KEY_ADDRESS_COMPONENTS)
            for (i in 0 until jArrAddressComponents.length()) {

                val jObjAddressComponents = jArrAddressComponents.getJSONObject(i)
                if (jObjAddressComponents.has(KEY_TYPES)) {

                    val jArrTypes = jObjAddressComponents.getJSONArray(KEY_TYPES)
                    for (j in 0 until jArrTypes.length()) {

                        when (jArrTypes.getString(j)) {

                            VALUE_LOCALITY, VALUE_POSTAL_TOWN -> {
                                return GeoLocation(jObjAddressComponents.getString(KEY_LONG_NAME), *geoCodes)
                            }

                            ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1 -> {
                                administrativeAreaLevel1 = jObjAddressComponents.getString(KEY_LONG_NAME)
                            }

                            else -> {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (i in 0 until jArrAddressComponents.length()) {

                val jObjAddressComponents = jArrAddressComponents.getJSONObject(i)
                if (jObjAddressComponents.has(KEY_TYPES)) {

                    val jArrTypes = jObjAddressComponents.getJSONArray(KEY_TYPES)

                    val typeList = ArrayList<String>()
                    for (j in 0 until jArrTypes.length()) {
                        typeList.add(jArrTypes.getString(j))
                    }

                    if (typeList.contains(VALUE_SUBLOCALITY)) {
                        var hasSubLocalityLevel = false
                        typeList.forEach { type ->
                            if (type.contains(VALUE_SUBLOCALITY_LEVEL)) {
                                hasSubLocalityLevel = true

                                if (type == VALUE_SUBLOCALITY_LEVEL_1) {
                                    return GeoLocation(jObjAddressComponents.getString(KEY_LONG_NAME), *geoCodes)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (!hasSubLocalityLevel) {
                            return GeoLocation(jObjAddressComponents.getString(KEY_LONG_NAME), *geoCodes)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (geoCodes.isNotEmpty()) return GeoLocation(administrativeAreaLevel1, geoCodes = *geoCodes)
     }
   }
return null
}
```

---

```
data class GeoLocation(val latitude: Double = 0.0, val longitude: Double = 0.0, val city: String? = null) : Parcelable {

constructor(city: String? = null, vararg geoCodes: Double) : this(geoCodes[0], geoCodes[1], city)

constructor(source: Parcel) : this(source.readDouble(), source.readDouble(), source.readString())

companion object {
    @JvmField
    val CREATOR = object : Parcelable.Creator<GeoLocation> {

        override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel) = GeoLocation(source)

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<GeoLocation?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}

override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    dest.writeDouble(latitude)
    dest.writeDouble(longitude)
    dest.writeString(city)
}

override fun describeContents() = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m in Brazil. Because of the regional details sometimes the city cames in differents ways. I think its the same in India and other countries. So, to prevent errors I make this verification:

```
private fun getAddress(latLng: LatLng): String {
    // 1
    val geocoder = Geocoder(this)
    val addresses: List<Address>?
    var city = "no"

    try {

        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1)

        if (null != addresses && !addresses.isEmpty()) { //prevent from error
             //sometimes the city comes in locality, sometimes in subAdminArea.
            if (addresses[0].locality == null) {

                city = addresses[0].subAdminArea
            } else {
                city = addresses[0].locality
            }

            }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("MapsActivity", e.localizedMessage)
    }

    return city
    }
```

You can also check if city returns "no". If so, wasn´t possible to get the user location.
Hope it helps.

Comment: `null != addresses && !addresses.isEmpty()` looks awfully in Kotlin.