# Google Maps JS API - Find name of place given location (latitude/longitude)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

Given a latitude/longitude, how can I get the **name** of the place at that location using 
Google Map's JS API?

The `Geocoder.geocode(..)` seems to be the way to go, but am not sure what's the best way to get the exact location name out of the API results.

Comment: maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296377/how-to-get-city-name-from-latitude-and-longitude-values-in-google-map-android

Comment: It's called reverse geocoding.  what exactly are you asking? what is the specific problem? google api for this is quite simple. so be more specific. what have you already tried?

Comment: Not sure what other specifics are needed, but perhaps the recent edit in the post should help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Geocoding API for mapping locations to addresses and addresses to locations.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

```
Geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': latLngObject }, callback);
```

The callback receives results and status.

The results are pretty accurate, but you'll have to rely on approximations nevertheless, as the user location can rarely be measured exactly.

Comment: Jorgen, nice avatar. Is it made automatically from your photo? Which tool did you use?

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty cool :) The company I work for order them from an artist. I'm afraid I don't know about how she makes them.

Comment: Yeah, that's really cool. I hoped they not drawn by hand, but generated but that's not the case unfortunatelly. Thank you for info :-)

Answer (score 7):

Reverse geocode is the term you are looking for:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse.html

Example:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding

Answer (score 3):

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

is the API call. **MAKE SURE THAT THERE IS NO SPACE IN THE latlng PARAMETER**