# How do I get location from the following array?

Tags: javascript

This is what the array looks like:

```
[GeoPlace {
  city: [Getter],
  province_state: [Getter],
  country: {
    long_name: 'Greece',
    short_name: 'GR'
  },
  formatted_address: 'Greece',
  location: {
    lat: 39.074208,
    lng: 21.824312
  },
  location_type: 'APPROXIMATE',
  location_bounds: {
    northeast: [Object],
    southwest: [Object]
  }
}]
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
if(!_.isNil(res) && _.isNil(err)) {
  console.log(res);
}
```

I want to be able to get just the location showing in the console.log.

Comment: Did you try `arr[0].location` ?

Comment: I assume you wan to know the name of
location with the help of Latitudes and Longitudes. You can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366610/google-maps-js-api-find-name-of-place-given-location-latitude-longitude)

Comment: Is it valid array?