# Finding city names and area details using Google Places API in android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-places-api, android-maps

I want to get details of the area I am standing in, I have the latitude and longitude using the LocationManager class, but how do I get the details such as name of the area, address etc? I don't want to use Geocoder due to restricted number of requests. How do find the details of the area using Google Places API?

Comment: This link might be helpful :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296377/how-to-get-city-name-from-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-in-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

Store the result of getFromLocation(double, double, int) method in an Address object, then call the method getLocality().