# Get the particular address using latitude and longitude

Tags: android, geolocation

I need to know is there any API ,from where i can receive the Address of the current place.Using location Manager i have receive the latitude and longitude of the current place ,but i need the address.

I have tried the below api.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ lat + "," + lon + &sensor=true"
```

But it is not showing the exact place .Can somebody help me.@Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296377/how-to-get-city-name-from-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-in-google-maps/2296416#2296416

Comment: You replace sensor with key=API_KEY.It will work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From a [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) object, you can call the [getFromLocation(double, double, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29) method.

like :-

```
private String getAddress(double latitude, double longitude) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                result.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                result.append(address.getCountryName());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

Another best answer is here [How to get city name from latitude and longitude coordinates in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296377/how-to-get-city-name-from-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-in-google-maps)

Comment: It doesn't work, address always empty, no errors, no exception, only empty.

Answer (score 15):

I have created a class for getting address for a particular Lat, Long. You can use this :

```
public class getReverseGeoCoding {
    private String Address1 = "", Address2 = "", City = "", State = "", Country = "", County = "", PIN = "";

    public void getAddress() {
        Address1 = "";
        Address2 = "";
        City = "";
        State = "";
        Country = "";
        County = "";
        PIN = "";

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = parser_Json.getJSONfromURL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + Global.curLatitude + ","
                    + Global.curLongitude + "&sensor=true");
            String Status = jsonObj.getString("status");
            if (Status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                JSONArray Results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
                JSONObject zero = Results.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray address_components = zero.getJSONArray("address_components");

                for (int i = 0; i < address_components.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject zero2 = address_components.getJSONObject(i);
                    String long_name = zero2.getString("long_name");
                    JSONArray mtypes = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
                    String Type = mtypes.getString(0);

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(long_name) == false || !long_name.equals(null) || long_name.length() > 0 || long_name != "") {
                        if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("street_number")) {
                            Address1 = long_name + " ";
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("route")) {
                            Address1 = Address1 + long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("sublocality")) {
                            Address2 = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("locality")) {
                            // Address2 = Address2 + long_name + ", ";
                            City = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_2")) {
                            County = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                            State = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("country")) {
                            Country = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("postal_code")) {
                            PIN = long_name;
                        }
                    }

                    // JSONArray mtypes = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
                    // String Type = mtypes.getString(0);
                    // Log.e(Type,long_name);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public String getAddress1() {
        return Address1;

    }

    public String getAddress2() {
        return Address2;

    }

    public String getCity() {
        return City;

    }

    public String getState() {
        return State;

    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;

    }

    public String getCounty() {
        return County;

    }

    public String getPIN() {
        return PIN;

    }

}
```

**JSON PARSER CLASS**

```
public class parser_Json {
    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {

        // initialize
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jObject = null;

        // http post
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jObject;
    }

}
```

Comment: The `curLongitude` is not being recognized. Is there a way I can solve it?

Comment: Just pass your latitude and longitude at the place of Global.curLongitude and Global.curLatitude.

Comment: thank you very much but I am getting this errors in logcat `02-26 16:48:21.900  31246-31246/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all E/log_tag﹕ Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-26 16:48:21.900  31246-31246/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all E/log_tag﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
02-26 16:48:21.910  31246-31246/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all E/log_tag﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
` and a null pointer exception in this `if (Status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {`.

Comment: This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.Try to run your code in **AsyncTask**. See this link for more detail [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: do I need to pass KEY with this URL ?

Answer (score 2):

```
    String longti = "0";
    String lati = "0";
    LocationManager locationManager;

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        1000, 1, new MyLocationListners());

    final Location location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 

//these are your longtitude and latitude  
         lati = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());  
         longti = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

//here we are getting the address using the geo codes(longtitude and latitude). 

 String ad = getAddress(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());


    private String getAddress(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
        String strAdd = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE,
                    LONGITUDE, 1);
            if (addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress
                            .append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                                    "\n");
                }
                strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                Log.w("My Current loction address",
                        "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
            } else {
                Log.w("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
        }
        return strAdd;
    }

public class MyLocationListners implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

    }
```

//make sure the gps and internet are on
//also sometimes, the location wont be visible at first time you run the code due to some //google services problem so you must restart the phone
//hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to modify the class given by [Vipul Purohit answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515682/get-the-particular-address-using-latitude-and-longitude#answer-16515848) to make it better

```
public class ReverseGeoCoding {
private String address1, address2, city, state, country, county, PIN;
private static final String LOG_TAG = ReverseGeoCoding.class.getSimpleName();

public ReverseGeoCoding(double latitude, double longitude) {
    init();
    retrieveData(latitude, longitude);
}

private void retrieveData(double latitude, double longitude) {
    try {
        String responseFromHttpUrl = getResponseFromHttpUrl(buildUrl(latitude, longitude));
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseFromHttpUrl);
        String status = jsonResponse.getString("status");
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
            JSONArray results = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("results");
            JSONObject zero = results.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray addressComponents = zero.getJSONArray("address_components");

            for (int i = 0; i < addressComponents.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject zero2 = addressComponents.getJSONObject(i);
                String longName = zero2.getString("long_name");
                JSONArray types = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
                String type = types.getString(0);


                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(longName)) {
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("street_number")) {
                        address1 = longName + " ";
                    } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("route")) {
                        address1 = address1 + longName;
                    } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("sublocality")) {
                        address2 = longName;
                    } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("locality")) {
                        // address2 = address2 + longName + ", ";
                        city = longName;
                    } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_2")) {
                        county = longName;
                    } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                        state = longName;
                    } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("country")) {
                        country = longName;
                    } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("postal_code")) {
                        PIN = longName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void init() {
    address1 = "";
    address2 = "";
    city = "";
    state = "";
    country = "";
    county = "";
    PIN = "";
}

private URL buildUrl(double latitude, double longitude) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json").buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("latlng", latitude + "," + longitude)
            .build();
    try {
        return new URL(uri.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "can't construct location object");
        return null;
    }
}

private String getResponseFromHttpUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            return scanner.next();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}

public String getAddress1() { return address1; }

public String getAddress2() { return address2; }

public String getCity() { return city; }

public String getState() { return state; }

public String getCountry() { return country; }

public String getCounty() { return county; }

public String getPIN() { return PIN; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

so many gave so many answer but all missed out the most crucial part.Below is how i achieved this: You need an API Key.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup
Just take time patiently go through the code.I used the inner class in  fragment.
code:-

```
private class DownloadRawData extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
              progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading........");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(LatLng... latLng) {
            ArrayList<String> strings=retrieveData(latLng[0].latitude,latLng[0].longitude);
            return strings;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if(progressDialog!=null)
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            LocationInfoDialog locationinfoDialog=new LocationInfoDialog(getActivity(),s);
            locationinfoDialog.show();
            locationinfoDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            locationinfoDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        address1 = "";
        address2 = "";
        city = "";
        state = "";
        country = "";
        county = "";
        PIN = "";
    }
    private String createUrl(double latitude, double longitude) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        init();
        return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?" + "latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&key=" + getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.map_apiid);
    }

    private URL buildUrl(double latitude, double longitude) {

        try {
            Log.w(TAG, "buildUrl: "+createUrl(latitude,longitude));
            return new URL(createUrl(latitude,longitude));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "can't construct location object");
            return null;
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String getResponseFromHttpUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                return scanner.next();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public String getAddress1() { return address1; }

    public String getAddress2() { return address2; }

    public String getCity() { return city; }

    public String getState() { return state; }

    public String getCountry() { return country; }

    public String getCounty() { return county; }

    public String getPIN() { return PIN; }
    private ArrayList<String> retrieveData(double latitude, double longitude) {
        ArrayList<String> strings=new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String responseFromHttpUrl = getResponseFromHttpUrl(buildUrl(latitude, longitude));
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseFromHttpUrl);
            String status = jsonResponse.getString("status");
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                JSONArray results = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("results");
                JSONObject zero = results.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray addressComponents = zero.getJSONArray("address_components");
                String formatadd= zero.getString("formatted_address");

                for (int i = 0; i < addressComponents.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject zero2 = addressComponents.getJSONObject(i);
                    String longName = zero2.getString("long_name");
                    JSONArray types = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
                    String type = types.getString(0);


                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(longName)) {
                        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("street_number")) {
                            address1 = longName + " ";

                        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("route")) {
                            address1 = address1 + longName;
                        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("sublocality")) {
                            address2 = longName;
                        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("locality")) {
                            // address2 = address2 + longName + ", ";
                            city = longName;
                        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_2")) {
                            county = longName;
                        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                            state = longName;
                        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("country")) {
                            country = longName;
                        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("postal_code")) {
                            PIN = longName;
                        }
                    }
                }
                strings.add(formatadd);
                strings.add(address1);
                strings.add(address2);
                strings.add(city);
                strings.add(county);
                strings.add(state);
                strings.add(country);

                strings.add(PIN);


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  strings;
    }
```

### Initialized like this:-

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Setting the title for the marker.
                // This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                new DownloadRawData().execute(latLng);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=latitude,longitude
and give latitude and longitude