# Get current location as TEXT with Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-maps-v2, mapfragment

I am currently retrieving the current location in my app but i also need the text of this location, or the city i am in at least, something like that.

Is there any known way i can do this?

This is what i have so far:

```
package ro.gebs.captoom.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

import com.example.captoom.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class LocationActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.preview_location);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());


        if (map != null) {
            Marker current_location_marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation)
                      .title("Current Location"));
        } else {

        }

        map.moveCamera(
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 10));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(
                CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

    }

}
```

Comment: You probably want to look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html, and use the getFromLocation() method?

Comment: Good stuff - if it's the answer you are looking for, plus it?

Comment: i don't have enough reputation for that:)

Comment: Ha! OK, thanks for trying/thinking about it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to get your current `latitude` and `longitude` then you can use `google api` to get current address component. See my answer on this question to get `address` from `lat long`

[Get the particular address using latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515682/get-the-particular-address-using-latitude-and-longitude/16515848#16515848)

Comment: Nice solution, i ended up using something similar! Thank you!