# how I can get the city name of my current position?

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm working with android studio and in a popup dialog I want that users can get their position but all I know to do is get my latitude and longitude.

**This is the code**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            latituteField.setText("Location not available");
            longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

in the MainActivity.Can you help me?

I've added this in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```

but it still says "Location not available".

---

Comment: by name you mean Address?

Comment: yes I mean the city: example. Florence

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need the [GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class to get [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) from a given Lat/Long. try the following:

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault()); //it is Geocoder
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
try {
    List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    int maxLines = address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();
    for (int i=0; i<maxLines; i++) {
    String addressStr = address.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
    builder.append(addressStr);
    builder.append(" ");
    }

String fnialAddress = builder.toString(); //This is the complete address.
} catch (IOException e) {}
  catch (NullPointerException e) {}
```

Code below should work for you: (Check the inline comments regarding your code)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
private TextView latituteField;
private TextView longitudeField;
private TextView addressField; //Add a new TextView to your activity_main to display the address
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
    addressField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView05); //Make sure you add this to activity_main


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
        latituteField.setText("Location not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //You had this as int. It is advised to have Lat/Loing as double.
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();

    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        int maxLines = address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();
        for (int i=0; i<maxLines; i++) {
            String addressStr = address.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
            builder.append(addressStr);
            builder.append(" ");
        }

        String fnialAddress = builder.toString(); //This is the complete address.

        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
        addressField.setText(fnialAddress); //This will display the final address.

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle IOException
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // Handle NullPointerException
    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work! When I launch the app on my phone it says "Unfortunately,My Application has stopped". Does it work for you?

Comment: Nono I solved it and it works but in TextView02,TextView04 and TextView05 it says "Location not available"

Comment: Are you using it on a device or the emulator?

Comment: I'm trying on my phone

Comment: **System.err: java.io.IOException: Service not Available**

Answer (score 15):

You need to execute the Geocoder in a **AsyncTask** (or in a Thread not in the same ThreadGroup as the UI Thread)!

```
public void getCityName(final Location location, final OnGeocoderFinishedListener listener) {
   new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<Address>>() {
      @Override
      protected List<Address> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
         Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.ENGLISH);
         List<Address> results = null;
         try {
            results = coder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
         } catch (IOException e) {
            // nothing
         }
         return results;
      }
        
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> results) {
         if (results != null && listener != null) {
            listener.onFinished(results);
         }
      }
   }.execute();
}
```

With this abstract Listener

```
public abstract class OnGeocoderFinishedListener {
   public abstract void onFinished(List<Address> results);
}
```

Now call the method like this:

```
getCityName(location, new OnGeocoderFinishedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onFinished(List<Address> results) {
      // do something with the result
   }
});
```

Hope this will help some of you!

Comment: [Here is a list of methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address) to get the city name from the `Address` object. Often [`getLocality`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address#getLocality()) will work, but sometimes it will return null and then you will need other methods like `getSubAdminArea`, `getSubLocality`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google api to get current location address. Check out my answer in this post go get your city.

[How to get city name from latitude and longitude coordinates in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296377/how-to-get-city-name-from-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-in-google-maps/16515890#16515890)