# Find city name from my location

Tags: android, geolocation

Is there a way I can get the name of the city from my current location (Android)? I know how to get the lattitue/long but if there is a concrete example then better

thank you

Comment: Some web service perhaps?

Comment: You need GeoCoder class.
Refer to this if it helps.
[Get City Name of Current Position][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221614/how-i-can-get-the-city-name-of-my-current-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
     try{
     List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);//lat and lon is the latitude and longitude in double
     if (addresses.size() > 0) 
     String cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
     }
     catch (IOException e) {}
     catch (NullPointerException e) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use google's API

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=<LAT>,<LNG>&sensor=true`

Put your latitude and longitude in the right place and use a JSONObject to parse the results

Answer (score 0):

Try out this, hope it helps. Excuse the loop, just took it out from a recent work of mine.

Take a look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html).

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);
for(int i=0; i<addresses.size(); ++i)
{
    address = addresses.get(i);
     string city = address.getLocality();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this article could could help you: http://www.devlper.com/2010/07/geocoding-and-reverse-geocoding-in-android/
It also provides its source code.

Else, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545853/android-geocoder-not-returning-city):

```
public class AndroidFromLocation extends Activity {

double LATITUDE = 37.42233;
double LONGITUDE = -122.083;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   TextView myLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mylatitude);
   TextView myLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mylongitude);
   TextView myAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myaddress);

   myLatitude.setText("Latitude: " + String.valueOf(LATITUDE));
   myLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + String.valueOf(LONGITUDE));

   Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

   try {
   List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

   if(addresses != null) {
   Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
   StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
   for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
   strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
  }
 myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
}
else{
myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
}
} catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");
 }

 }
 }
```

Also, check this concrete example: http://www.smnirven.com/blog/2009/10/09/reverse-geocode-lookup-using-google-maps-api-on-android-revisited/   and get the full code from [here](https://github.com/smnirven/geocoding_example).