# Geocoder cannot update address using while changing latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps

It goes inside onLocationChanged block every time I move the map and new latitude and long is also fetched but it does not update the address but shows the address which was first loaded. I am using the following for updating the address:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.e("change" , "change");

    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    try {
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses.isEmpty()) {

            Log.e("TAG", "Waiting for Location");
        }
        else {
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Log.e("TAG", addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
                //yourtextfieldname.setText(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality() +", " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Address:- " + addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + addresses.get(0).getLocality(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // getFromLocation() may sometimes fail
    }
}
```

Comment: you have commented the line which updates the text on the textview!

Comment: i still have a Log there

Comment: and do you see the log in logcat ?

Comment: yes i do see the log

Comment: and what does it log ?

Comment: it logs only the first time address and next time even if it goes inside this block still loads the same previous address even thought i am getting different lat and long

Comment: how diff are the lat and long, if they are mostly the same. you will get same address

Comment: 27.712028, 85.299403 and 27.713327,85.323612

Comment: okay , upvoted your question. good luck

Answer (score 1):

Geocoder is not available in some devices, use Google API Client instead of Geocoder

Comment: how to use that? can you help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296377/how-to-get-city-name-from-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-in-google-maps

Please go through this link, it will help you