# How to get a user's current city?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation

I want to get the user's current location through my Android Application. I keep seeing the error message that should be displayed if anything goes wrong getting the location from the phone's GPS. Can you guys please tell me what's wrong with my codes?

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.apple.project;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;

    TextView textView;

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                    }
                } else {
                    LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    try {
                        textView.setText(hereLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not found!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        try {
                            textView.setText(hereLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not found!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No permission granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public String hereLocation(double lat, double lng) {
        String cur_city_name = "";

        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this,
                Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0)
                cur_city_name = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + cur_city_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return cur_city_name;
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout        
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()` returns last cached location, use `mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` where you need to provide callback and in that callback you will receive latest location.

Comment: @Drickuss Merguez deleted my answer. I don't do a coding job here.We can show you want to do and you need to try it your self :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it works perfect

```
 public String getAddress(double lats, double lons) {

                Geocoder geocoder;
                double lat = lats;
                double lon = lons;
                geocoder = new Geocoder(YourActivityName.this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<android.location.Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (addresses != null) {

                    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); 
                    String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                    String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); 

                    return address;
                } else {
                    return "failed";
                }


            }
```

Comment: @Drickuss Merguez if you need help ask me

Comment: Please check this out     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41445485/get-the-users-current-city/41445608?noredirect=1#comment70097898_41445608

Comment: @Drickuss Merguez do you need an answer?

Comment: Yesssss please!

Answer (score 1):

refer the link

[How to get city name from latitude and longitude coordinates in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296377/how-to-get-city-name-from-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-in-google-maps)

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) 
{
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
}
else
{
   // do your staff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
    geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lati, longi, 1);
        // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
      //  addresses.add();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!addresses.isEmpty()){
        address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
    }
```