# Get the user's current city

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation

Hi I posted a question concerning the same topic a while ago, after following your advices I can feel that I'm getting closed to solving my problem. The App does is now crashing as I click on the button with the following error message in the monitor:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.apple.myapp1, PID: 10081
                                       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                           at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                           at com.example.apple.myapp1.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.apple.myapp1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
double lats, lons;
Geocoder geocoder;
double lat = lats;
double lon = lons;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnGetLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new         ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Fetching location...");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (addresses != null) {
                String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                TextView cellText = (TextView)     findViewById(R.id.cellText);
                cellText.setText(address);

            } else {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                TextView cellText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cellText);
                cellText.setText("Error");
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please click the button below to get your location" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Me" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cellText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lacationText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: looks like addresses is an empty array. You have to double check geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);

Comment: Also test for empty not just null.

Comment: In the code that you have posted, `lats` and `lons` variables are not initialized. And as a result your `lat` and `lon` are also not initialized.

Comment: @GuyBouallet So what other value can i give to addresses?

Comment: @DavidBradley talking about lats and lons? or addresses?

Comment: @GuyBouallet the point that you evoked seems to be the main problem. How can I solve it?

Comment: @DrickussMerguez I was referring to the addresses list. You check for null, but your code will fail if the list is empty but not null. From the doc's: "Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the condition `if (addresses != null) { }`  you should also check for the length of the addresses, since there might be 0.

```
if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
    String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
    String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
    String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    TextView cellText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cellText);
    cellText.setText(address);

} else {
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    TextView cellText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cellText);
    cellText.setText("Error");
}
```

if it wasn't able to find at least one address you should consider showing the user an empty state.

It also seems like you forgot to initialize your latitude and longitude before calling              `addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);`

To properly initialize this, do the following:

```
Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(__YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME__ + ".LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA");
lat = location.getLatitude();
lon = location.getLongitude();
```

If you need any more help check out this [page from android](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html). It should hold all information you need.

### EDIT:

I kind of assumed you we're further in the process, but it seems you have only tried to get the location of a latLong position, which you have never obtained. To achieve obtaining the address you will have to have the user's lcoation first.

Again, the page mentioned above should explain everything you need to obtain the location, but make sure of the following:

**1. Have the permission to access the user's location** (for Android 6+ use [Runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html))

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationupdates" >

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

**2. Get an instance of the GoogleApi and ave your activity implement some callbacks**

For the Callbacks

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener
```

Then in your `OnCreate()` create an instance of GoogleApiClient.

```
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

**3. Obtain the location from the GoogleApiClient**
Do this by implementing the callbacks properly.

```
/**
 * Represents a geographical location.
 */
protected Location mLastLocation;

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
     // Gets the best and most recent location currently available, which may be null
     // in rare cases when a location is not available.
     mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
     if (mLastLocation != null) {
         // Determine whether a Geocoder is available.
         if (!Geocoder.isPresent()) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "no geocoder available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return;
         }
     }
 }
```

**4. Now obtain the lat long and try to obtain the address as attempted before.**

```
lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
lon = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = null;
try {
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This should be enough to obtain the actual adress of the device and ask the geocoder for the addresses. I altered the example a bit to simplify for this question. Google's example handles fetching the address a bit more clean. Note that you will also have to disconnect the GoogleApi when stopping your activity and such. Again I recommend reading the entire [Tutorial page](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html). You can find en example of their implementation [on this page on GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationAddress/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationaddress)

Comment: I keep seeing "Error" displayed

Comment: Yes that probably means the Geocoder can't find an address for the given latitude and longitude. Are you giving a latlong that is in a remote area? Check the API for what you should do when not being able to find an address

Comment: how can i check if im giving lat and ling in a remote area? and how to set what should be done in such a case from the API, I'm kinda new in the AndroidStudio world. :)

Comment: It seems you havn't initialized your lat and lon. I updated my answer, this should probably do the trick

Comment: Cannot resolve LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, Seems like we're getting closer!! :)

Comment: I seems that the class Constants is custom to the example. *https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationAddress/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationaddress/Constants.java*
You could replace this with `YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME + ".LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA"`

Comment: i see package com.example.apple.myapp1; it means that MY_PACKAGE_NAME is com.example.apple.myapp1 right?

Comment: Yes I think that should be it. Otherwise you could try *getApplicationContext().getPackageName();*

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.apple.myapp1, PID: 8711
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.example.apple.myapp1.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference

Comment: I see you had a little more to do to obtain the location of the user then I expected. I thinks my edit should help you enough with obtain the location of the device. In the last link to github you can find the mainactivity Google used for their example. Everything you need is in there.